# Select results where value of column is not equal to value of other column from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to make a voting script, where people can rate teachers, but I have a problem.

I want the script to only show teachers that you haven't rated before, because it doesn't make sence to rate the same thing again and again.

I have 2 tables for this:
teacher and rating

From the "teacher" table, i need the values of teacherId, teacherName and teacherImage

From the "rating" table, i want to compare the value of userId with the id of the logged in user (I have a variable with the value of the user)

But for testing, i just use the id "2".

When that is done, i want it to show every teacher, that this user haven't voted on yet. I have tried a lot of ways, but none of them worked as I wanted to.

My latest query is:

```
SELECT t.teacherId, t.teacherName, t.teacherImage, r.userId, r.teacherId
FROM teacher t, rating r
WHERE r.userId = 2 AND t.teacherId != r.teacherId
```

If anyone has an idea on how I could get this to work, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any rating records for those teachers that has not been rated by a particular user. You may retrieve the list of teachers that has been rated by the user then use NOT IN.

```
SELECT teacherId, 
       teacherName, 
       teacherImage
  FROM teacher 
 WHERE teacherId NOT IN (SELECT teacherId
                           FROM rating
                          WHERE userId = 2)
```